# Why am I getting the error "NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Unsafe" when trying to load sounds using the LWJGL library?

Tags: java, lwjgl, noclassdeffounderror

This is the screenshot of my Eclipse project files.
[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

I get the error below when I try to initiated a `new Sound("Res/MouseClick.ogg")` object in my class `AudioPlayer` at line 15.

```
package com.game;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.newdawn.slick.Music;
import org.newdawn.slick.Sound;

public class AudioPlayer {
    public static Map<String, Sound> soundMap = new HashMap<String, Sound>();
    public static Map<String, Music> musicMap = new HashMap<String, Music>();

    public static void load() {
        try {
            soundMap.put("menu_sound", new Sound("Res/MouseClick.ogg")); // <- throws error
            musicMap.put("music", new Music("Res/Background.ogg"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Music getMusic(String key) {
        return musicMap.get(key);
    }

    public static Sound getSound(String key) {
        return soundMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Unsafe
at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.MemoryUtilSun$AccessorUnsafe.getUnsafeInstance(MemoryUtilSun.java:74)
at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.MemoryUtilSun$AccessorUnsafe.<init>(MemoryUtilSun.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:166)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:404)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:590)
at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.MemoryUtil.loadAccessor(MemoryUtil.java:324)
at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:66)
at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.openal.ALC10.alcOpenDevice(ALC10.java:202)
at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.openal.AL.init(AL.java:160)
at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:138)
at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:102)
at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:201)
at slick/org.newdawn.slick.openal.SoundStore$1.run(SoundStore.java:295)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
at slick/org.newdawn.slick.openal.SoundStore.init(SoundStore.java:292)
at slick/org.newdawn.slick.Sound.<init>(Sound.java:54)

at Wave/com.game.AudioPlayer.load(AudioPlayer.java:15)
at Wave/com.game.Game.<init>(Game.java:37)
at Wave/com.game.Game.main(Game.java:157)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Unsafe
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 23 more
```

Comment: This code uses lwjgl library and "unsafe"? Maybe folks at jvm-gaming.org or lwjgl.org will be closer to the code involved, if you aren't able to get help here. I've tinkered with jorbis library for loading ogg to memory and might be able to help with that, if you want to pursue that as a work-around.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You started pretty well with asking your first question here. Still there are few things you want to keep in mind for future questions (as this question has seen several edits from different people). 1) Always include all relevant information as (`formatted`) text in your question description. 2) When adding images then embed them into your description and not as a link to some off-site resource (which may go offline sometime again). 3) Take care when choosing the question tags – double-check whether they really refer to what you think they do.

Comment: There are further hints in [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and I also suggest to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works. – Don't forget to accept an answer when it answers your question.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer (tick check-mark next to an answer) when it answers your question. In this way your question won't show up as _unanswered_ in the searches anymore.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From your posted IDE screenshot I can see that you are using

- Java 12, and
- the Java Module System (`module-info.java`)

Note that `sun/misc/Unsafe` is a (legacy) ***Java internal API*** which for that reason and by default is encapsulated (hidden) away when using the Java Module System.

In order for your application (and your used library) to access it, you need to explicitly include it in your `module-info.java` by adding `requires jdk.unsupported;`

Alternatively, you may also not use the Java Module System – in which case it should simply work. However, I recommend to continue using the module system.

Comment: Thanks. I was using jlink for a custom runtime and needed to include the jdk.unsupported module.

Comment: How do you get from `sun/misc/Unsafe` - which part of the error - to `jdk.unsupported` - which needs to go into the module-info file?